# Channelized lanes for QSFP+ and QSFP28

Tags: configuration

Probably a simple answer, but as I have nothing currently to test this out on I thought I would ask.

Once you breakout from 40GB to 4x10GB or 100GB to 4X25GB, are you able to configure each lane as if it was its own individual interface like you would 4 separate ports? Or do the lanes need to share the same port configuration between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be configured separately (at least on HPE Synergy 40Gb F8 switches).